# Discrete Math and non-empty relations

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$ and $B = \{w,x,y\}$, then a non-empty relations on $A$ is: 
$\{ (b,c), (b,d）\}$

Can someone explain why this is true? I thought that the requirements for any relations of a set has to be such that for $(x,y)$, $x$ has to be a subset of $y$, and $x,y$ have to be a subset of $A$. How is $b$ a subset of $c$?

Comment: Does $\{ b, c \}$ denote the subset consisting of $b$ and $c$ or the ordered pair $(b, c)$?  In the context of the question, the latter makes a lot more sense.  Moreover, $(\{b, c\}, \{b, d\})$ typically would denote an element of $2^A \times 2^A$, that is, the Cartesian product of the power set of $A$ with itself.

Answer (score 2):

A relation on $A$ is simply a subset of the Cartesian product $A \times A$. For $A=\{a,b,c,d\}$, both $(b,c)$ and $(b,d)$ are contained in $A \times A$; therefore, $\{(b,c),(b,d)\}$ is a relation on $A$.

Comment: How come when A={{1},{2},{1,2}}, then （{1},{2}) is not a relation?

Comment: If $A=\{\{1\},\{2\},\{1,2\}\}$, then $\{\{\{1\},\{2\}\}\}$ is a relation on $A$, not $\{\{1\},\{2\}\}$.

Comment: In my textbook it doesn't show that as a relation when it said it listed every possible subset relation

Comment: Apologies, my notation was _way_ off. I used $\{\}$ where I should have used $()$. But anyway, the set $\{(\{1\},\{2\})\}$ is in fact a relation on $A$. Remember, relations _are_ sets, so an ordered pair $(\{1\},\{2\})$ by itself cannot be a relation, though it can be (and, here, is) an _element_ of a relation.

Comment: If your textbook does not list $\{(\{1\},\{2\})\}$ as a relation, then either you have copied $A$ from the textbook incorrectly or it is simply an error in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Any set $$R \subseteq A \times A = \{(x,y) \mid x \in A ,\,y \in A\} $$ is a relation on $A $. Since $$\{(b,c), (b,d)\} \subseteq A \times A$$ holds, it is indeed a relation on $ A$.